# How to shuffle inner div contents using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to shuffle the inner contents of a div using javascript. I can shuffle the div positions but cannot shuffle the inner contents. I want to shuffle in such a way that will return like Position 1: Third, Position 2: First, Position 3: Second and so on. I can shuffle the div positions like below but cannot update the contents. Can anyone help?

```js
shuffle();
function shuffle() {
    var container = document.getElementById("mainshuffle");
    var elementsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(container.getElementsByClassName("diffpos"));
    elementsArray.forEach(function (element) {
        container.removeChild(element);
    });
    shuffleArray(elementsArray);
    elementsArray.forEach(function (element) {
        container.appendChild(element);
    });
}

function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainshuffle">
    <div class="diffpos">
        <p>Position 1: First</p>
        <img src="position1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="diffpos">
        <p>Position 2: Second</p>
        <img src="position2.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="diffpos">
        <p>Position 3: Third</p>
        <img src="position3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I can shuffle the div positions but cannot shuffle the inner contents."* What does that mean? Moving the divs inherently moves their contents. Did you want to shuffle the contents **within** the divs? (For instance, so that the image might be in front of the paragraph?) If so, do what you're doing, but with the contents of the divs, not just the divs. It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: *"I want to shuffle in such a way that will return like Position 1: Third, Position 2: First, Position 3: Second..."* So you want to break apart the text node containing the text after the `:`, and then move the text nodes between the divs? (Or just replace the `1`, `2`, or `3` with a different number.)

Comment: Yes I want to interchange the  text node containing the text after the : and then move the text nodes between the divs. For example, first it may show Position 2: First and image position1.jpg ,Position 1: Third and image position3.jpg,Position 3: Second and image position2.jpg and so on

Comment: Your best bet is to give it a go. The code you haven't doesn't try to do that. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the content of `p tag`
refactor your html like this

```
<div id="mainshuffle">
  <p id="p_shuffle">Position 1: First</p>
  <img class="img_shuffle" src="...">
</div>
```

Store the content in a array for example:

```
const contentArr = ['position 1: first', 'position 2: second', 'position 3: third']
```

then change the content of p tag by using contentArr index like this

```
function shuffleContent(i) {
  // i is the index of content you want to use depending on which content you want
  const newContent = contentArr[i];
  const shuffleP = document.getElementById('p_shuffle');
  shuffleP.textContent = newContent;
}
```

Comment: But there are multiple p pags.